# How to replace (n) occurrences of a character with (n-1) occurrences of the same character in JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

My data is

```
Hello ***** World
```

I need

```
Hello **** World
```

So basically 5 occurrences of star replaced with 4 occurrences of star. How can I do that In regex javascript.

NOTE: The number of star is dynamic.

I tried this but not sure how to replace the capturing group:

```js
console.log("Hello ***** World".replace(/[a-zA-Z](.*)/gm,"$1||$3"));
```

UPDATE:

Wiktor's solution works like a charm. But not sure how to translate this to my actual problem I am facing in my regex. So I thought, it will be worth to post my actual problem.

My Data is this:

```
1.  Hello


•   World
```

I need this

```
1.  Hello

•   World
```

I need to reduce number of extra lines to n-1 between

```
[Numeric].[Space][Any text]

and

•[Three Spaces][AnyText]
```

*and vice vera*

```
•[Three Spaces][AnyText]

and 

[Numeric].[Space][Any text]
```

Note: Sorry for poor explanation. I am noob in regex.

Comment: You change the `\*` in his answer into a space. `/( +) /` (or `*` instead of `+`) if you also want to remove the last space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture one or more asterisks and then match without capturing another (last in the sequence) asterisk, and replace with the backreference to the group value:

```js
console.log("Hello ***** World".replace(/(\*+)\*/g, "$1"));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDlzI9/1).

There are other similar solutions here:

```js
console.log("Hello ***** World".replace(/(\*)\*(?!\*)/g, '$1'));
console.log("Hello ***** World".replace(/(?<=\*)\*(?!\*)/g, ''));
```

See [this regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/JDlzI9/3) and [regex demo #3](https://regex101.com/r/JDlzI9/4/).

In `(\*)\*(?!\*)`, the first `*` is captured into Group 1, then an asterisk that has no other asterisk to the right of it is matched, and the `$1` replacement does the job as in the first solution.

The `(?<=\*)\*(?!\*)` regex simply matches any asterisk that has an asterisk immediately on the left and no asterisk immediately on the right (that is why the replacement pattern is empty).

Applying this to a **decreasing the amount of line breaks between two strings** problem can look like

```js
text = text.replace(/(\d+\.\s.*(?:\r\n?|\n)+)(?:\r\n?|\n)(?=•\s{3})/g, '$1').replace(/(•\s{3}.*(?:\r\n?|\n)+)(?:\r\n?|\n)(?=\d+\.\s)/g, '$1')
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/7oVXT9/1) and [another, "vice versa", demo](https://regex101.com/r/7oVXT9/2).

Here, `(?:\r\n?|\n)` replaced the `\*` pattern and matches CRLF, LF or CR line endings. `\s{3}` matches any three whitespaces chars. `\d+\.\s` matches one  or more digits, `.` and a whitespace, and `.*` matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (the rest of a line pattern). Lookaheads, `(?=...)`, are used to make sure consecutive matches are matched.

Comment: Change `/(\*+)\*/g` into `/(\**)\*/g` if you want to allow the removal of the last asterisk.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I do not think that standalone asterisks need removing. I understand it that only two or more asterisk sequences must be handled.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. I tried to translate your solution to mine but not sure how to translate it to my actual problem. Can you help me with that. I am sorry, I am noob in regex.