# Javascript Regex replace repetitions with exact one less

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which has a character (`\n`) repeated multiple times. I want to replace this repetitions by just **one repetition less**.

So let's suppose that we have a string like this (\n repeats 3 times)

```
hello\n\n\ngoodbye
```

Ans I want to convert it to this (\n repeats 2 times)

```
hello\n\ngoodbye
```

I know how to find out with regex when the occurrence repeats (e.g. `/\n\n+/g`), but I don't know how to capture the exact number of repetitions to use it in the replace.

Is possible to do that with Regex?

Comment: You don't need the _"exact number of repetitions"_. You only need one `\n` + (all other `\n`s).

Comment: @anubhava A duplicate of **[How to replace (n) occurrences of a character with (n-1) occurrences of the same character in JavaScript Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481090/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```sh
/\n(\n*)/g
```

And replace using: `$1`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Coauc0/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\n`: Match a line break
- `(\n*)`: Match 0 or more line breaks and capture them in 1st capture group. Note that we are capturing one less `\n`s in this capture group
- Replacement of `$1` will place all `\n`s with back-reference of 1st capture group, thus reducing line breaks by one.

**Code:**

```js
const string = 'hello\n\n\ngoodbye';
console.log(string);

const re = /\n(\n*)/g;
var repl = string.replace(re, "$1");

console.log(repl);
```

Comment: Yes, great! Thanks anubhava!

Answer (score 2):

replace `(\n*)\n` with `$1`?

```js
let str = 'hello\n\n\ngoodbye'
console.log(str)
console.log(str.replace(/(\n*)\n/,'$1'))
```